# Simple Prolog predicate - statement is always evaluated as false

Tags: prolog

I've just started Prolog and truly wonder why the following lines, specifically the 'is' part, always produces false:

```
highest(L) :-
    path(_,_,Z),
    Z >= L,
    L is Z.
highestWrap :-
    highest(0).
```

highestWrap is called.

Thanks in advance and have a beautiful day!

Comment: Note: Somehow the wildcard operators _ are omitted between the commas.

Comment: `is` is not a fancy way to write `=` in Prolog, it evaluates an arithmetic expression on the right hand side. But be aware that variables in Prolog would be better called "assignables" because they cannot change value once bound.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a path with length `0`, this will not work, and even then, it will likely not yield what you want: it will just say true.

In Prolog variables can only be set once, that means that if `L` is set to `0`, then it remains `0`, unless you backtrack over that assignment.

Here it thus means that you call `highest(0)`, next you instruct Prolog to call `path(_, _, Z)` and this can result in zero, one or more solutions. In case there are no `path(_, _, Z)`s, then the call will fail. But in case there are, then `Z` will (if I make correct assumptions about the predicate), have a numerical value, for example `7`.

Now the condition `Z >= L` of course holds in that case (if `Z` is `7`), so that is nog the problem. But now you specify `L is Z`. That thus means that you call `0 is 7`. The [**`is/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) predicate aims to solve the expression of the second argument (that expression is `7` in the example, so there is not much to solve), and then *aims* to unify it with the term on the left side. But since `0` is not equal to `7` that fails.

If you want to obtain the highest path, you can for example make use of the [**`aggregate`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) library:

```
:- use_module(library(aggregate)).

highest(L) :-
    aggregate(Max(Z), path(_,_,Z), Max(L)).
```

You can then call it with `higest(X)` to unify `X` with the highest value for `Z` in a call to `path(_, _, Z)`.